# Connection refused when running testcafe

Tags: reactjs, windows, testing, firewall, testcafe

I have been using TestCafe for a while to run e2e-tests on my React application. However, after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 the tests will no longer run. When TestCafe starts I only see a warning saying "Connection refused".

I am behind a corporate network and it is IT-services that have upgraded my computer. Thus, I am not aware of what settings they are using. I can see that TestCafe tries to connect to my IPv4 address and I suspect that I have to open some port range in the Windows Firewall to let it through.

Another option would be if I could set TestCafe to use localhost instead of my IPv4 address.

Have anyone experienced similar issues with TestCafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like necessary ports are closed. You can specify custom ones using the ["--ports"](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--ports-port1port2) command parameter.

To specify a computer's hostname, use the ["--hostname"](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--hostname-name)  command parameter.

So, if you wish to use localhost instead of your IPv4 address, add the following command line parameter:

*--hostname localhost*